# search another device through my app

Tags: android

Is it possible to search another device through my device if a particular application is found in it?

I have an app "MY APP".I need to check if the same application is installed in another device which is paired to me using bluetooth.
Package manager searches the current device only.So is there any other option ?

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is nothing built into Android for this.

Comment: ok,,So is there any other way to restrict the bluetooth connection between devices having "MY APP" installed? Kindly help